# Flutter streambuilder not refreshing screens

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm creating a simple app and wanted to add login to it via firebase. It consists of two screens, TabsScreen and AuthScreen. My goal is to move the user after login/registration from AuthScreen to TabsScreen, or vice versa when the user logs out. It works correctly only when user is logging out, in order for the screen to refresh at login I have to restart the app.
What could be the cause of this not working?

Here's a snippet of my code

```
return MaterialApp(
home: StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return const TabsScreen();
            }
            return const AuthScreen();
          },),);
```

This is how I create a new user

```
final userCredentials = await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
  email: _enteredEmail,
  password: _enteredPassword,
);
```

And this logs the user out

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  },
  child: const Text('Log out'),
),
```

I know streambuilder is listening for changes correctly and firebase is adding a new user, but the screen is not updating.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Streambuilder not working as expected with Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66432406/flutter-streambuilder-not-working-as-expected-with-firebase)

Comment: Unfortunately no, my problem still persists because I can't even log into the app without restarting it, and this question refers to updating the status after manual changes in the backend. This may actually be related to tokens, but I don't see a solution on how to do it with the firebase_auth package. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I personally would use actual navigation to move between screens (not only replacing the widgets like that). [go_router](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) provides a way to navigate screens based on auth changes. See [Redirection topic](https://pub.dev/documentation/go_router/latest/topics/Redirection-topic.html)

Comment: And this is the solution. Thanks! Not only did I solve my problem, but I also learned a very useful package.

Comment: I think I'm having a problem outside of the shared code. I tried with a similar code, but the screen changes when I log in.

`builder: (context, snapshot) => snapshot.hasData ? TextButton(onPressed: FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut, child: Text('Sign out')) : TextButton( onPressed: FirebaseAuth.instance.signInAnonymously, child: Text('Sign in')),`

Comment: This is also what I was thinking about, although I did not make any changes to the folders other than lib. I had a very similar project before and everything worked fine.